# Converting image to grayscale in python using skimage.color.rgb2gray isn't working

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

I am using skimage.color.rgb2gray to convert image to grayscale. But the method isn't working. What am I missing?

[image: code written on jupyter notebook]

Comment: What's the shape of your array image ?

Comment: It is 2D. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Could you show the initialization for `circle_collection`?

Comment: `circle_collection = io.imread_collection('Shapes/Database/Train/Circle/*.png')
print(type(circle_collection), '\n\n', circle_collection)`

Result: (<class 'skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection'>, '\n\n', <skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection object at 0x111977c10>)